# Sum column values and show right below the column using label

Tags: asp.net

This is my gridview design.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="3"
                GridLines="Both" ShowFooter="True" CssClass="contentfont">
                <RowStyle Wrap="False" />                    
                <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" Height="25px" />
                <FooterStyle Forecolor="Black" BackColor="LightGray" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

After binding the columns from DB this grdiview has around 8 columns. Now I need to sum certain columns total values and show it right below the column by using labels. I can add footerrow with label if add, delete, edit and update functionality is required. Since the gridview is readonly and no updation is required, I am confused how to achieve this.

**Query:**

I am using this query to bind the grid. I need to sum all columns except first two in my select query.

```
command.CommandText = "select AppName, Year, RevisedValue, SalesProfit, Variance, MonthlyProfit, QuarterProfit, YearlyProfit from Reports
```

Can anyone help me solve this.

Comment: You can probably handle this in your `SELECT` statement. Can you post the code where you retrieve the data for the `GridView`?

Comment: You mean the piece of select query // command.CommandText = "select AppName, Year, RevisedValue, SalesProfit, Variance, MonthlyProfit, QuarterProfit, YearlyProfit from Reports

Comment: Yes, along with whatever data controls you are using (i.e., `SqlDataSource` vs. `OdbcDataSource`, `DataAdapter` vs. `DataReader`, etc). Your `SELECT` statement only pulls back 8 fields. Where do the other 6 come from? Also, which specific columns need summed? This type of information should be added to your question.

Comment: pete - Updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying how you store your data, so I'll just go with a datatable, which will be called DTable in my example.

Add the following ode to your markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" /* .... */ OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">                
</asp:GridView>
```

*EDIT* From here I edited the post, to change it with code I tested in a sample project. I used the AdventureWorks Database to get some sample data. To make it quick I used Linq-to-Entites to get the data and bind it to the GridView.
After this I used the above mentioned `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound` to calculate the footer values.

```
    void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            using (var context = new AdventureWorks2008R2Entities())
            {
                var result = context.Products.Where(p => p.ListPrice != 0)
                                    .Select(x => new
                                    {
                                        Name = x.Name,
                                        ListPrice = x.ListPrice,
                                        StandardCost = x.StandardCost
                                    })
                                    .Take(5);
                GridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new AdventureWorks2008R2Entities())
        {
            var result = context.Products.Where(p => p.ListPrice != 0)
                                .Select(x => new
                                {
                                    Name = x.Name,
                                    ListPrice = x.ListPrice,
                                    StandardCost = x.StandardCost
                                })
                                .Take(5);
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = result.ToList().Sum(x => x.ListPrice).ToString();
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = result.ToList().Sum(x => x.StandardCost).ToString();
            }   
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image: GridView calculated footer]

*Note: * This code is far from optimal, because I am querying the database twice. Please don't use it in productive code. It is probably better to get the data, store it in a database and then calculate the Sum() of the needed fields in memory.